# Idea's to launch an application (with parameters) from a pdf document

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, document

I have a small problem at work. For years the company has stored their documents on a network drive, using folder access writes to control access. The Company has grown somewhat and this option is no longer ...'desirable'.

We are now in the process of migrating all the documents onto an encrypted server, with access to it controlled via SQL (a table with the document details - accessed via an ID).

Although this is going well (in general) and access to the documents in most respects is now alot simpler for the average user, we face a problem. Some users (management in particular) used to write hyperlinks in PDF and Powerpoint documents to open external documents (e.g. "\network_path\required_file.jpeg" - would open a jpg, to show an audience the latest version of a product).

In response I have written a small program to launch the documents via command-line parameters (e.g "\network_drive\launch.exe -1234" would launch the document with ID 1234). This works perfectly in Powerpoint. But alas when we convert to a pdf, the links no longer work. I have downloaded a trial version of Adobe Pro XI, and although I can create a link to launch the program, I can not add the parameters to this link.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could approach this? The solution needs to be simple enough for the average user (and management) to be able to control and access the correct documents.

I have thought about using a script but can't think of a way to do this so that it is simple enough for the average user.

Comment: Will something like this work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#app_reg

Comment: Thanks DF, not sure if it will work, but I'll look into it. I think this requires a windows registry entry? The program will are using (at this point) is just an exe sitting on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Action** dictionary of **Link** annotation can have **Win** sub-dictionary with **P** key, containing ["parameter string to be passed to the application"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). It looks like Acrobat is handicapped and doesn't allow to add/edit Win dictionary entries. You can use freeware [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) for that. E.g., I added a link to launch Notepad with a parameter, here's result (pretty-printed with [mutool](http://www.mupdf.com/)):

```
12 0 obj
<<
  /A <<
    /F 30 0 R
    /S /Launch
    /Win <<
      /F (C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe)
      /O (open)
      /P (/A c:\\boot.ini)
    >>
  >>
...
```

Comment: Works perfectly, the only problem is that adobe still won't accept the params, so everyone will need the alternative...

Comment: @Bob, That's interesting. When I wrote an answer, I had access to older Acrobat version (9.5.3) -- I checked that links with a parameter list worked OK (though after struggling, via registry hack, with usual security paranoia). Now, that you said adobe doesn't accept the params, I checked latest (11) Reader, and yes, you are right. Sorry if I mislead you. Not only Adobe PDF editor doesn't implement all PDF specification features, but even their Reader is now not ISO-32000 compliant anymore. Not good.

Comment: Yea I've read alot of complaints about it all over the place! Adobe is not doing so well atm (they were also hacked not long ago). Their loss tho, our company is now using PDF-XChange Viewer. Thanks for your help